# Can I call an inner class from the outer class's classmethod?

Tags: python, python-2.7, elasticsearch

I'm working with the elasticsearch_dsl library but this question is broadly applicable to python.

I want to define a method that creates an index named: `test__YYYY-MM-DD`

```
class Test(DocType):
    content = Text()

    class Meta:
        index = 'test'

    @classmethod
    def create_index(cls):
        now = datetime.datetime.utcnow().strftime('%Y-%m-%d')
        test = Index('{}__{}'.format(cls.Meta.index, now))
                                         ^^^ this does not exist
        test.doc_type(cls)
        test.create()
```

How can I get access to `index` field that lives on the `Meta` inner class?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> I'm working with the `elasticsearch_dsl` library but this question is broadly applicable to Python.

It is not broadly applicable to Python, actually. In a normal class, accessing `cls.Meta.index` would just work as usual here. [`DocType` has a metaclass](https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch-dsl-py/blob/13a470aa1cc788d50ccba430f63118444bf4cdd0/elasticsearch_dsl/document.py#L108-L109) that [removes `Meta` from the class namespace](https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch-dsl-py/blob/13a470aa1cc788d50ccba430f63118444bf4cdd0/elasticsearch_dsl/document.py#L30).  If I'm reading the source code correctly, the attribute you're looking for should be available at `cls._doc_type.index`.

```
>>> class Example(DocType):
...     class Inner:
...         index = 'inner_var'
...     class Meta:
...         index = 'meta_var'
...     @classmethod
...     def foo(cls):
...         print(cls.Inner.index)
...         print(cls._doc_type.index)
...         
>>> Example.foo()
inner_var
meta_var
```

*Note:* The presence of a leading underscore on the `DocTypeOptions` instance, i.e. `_doc_type`, suggests private API. Perhaps you should look for a public API to create index instead.